# Easiest way to make perl application for windows run on startup in code

Tags: windows, perl

What is the easiest way to make a perl app run at startup in perl code?
For example: to copy it to the "allusers" startup folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Task Scheduler. In Windows 7 (older Win versions are very similar):
Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Task Scheduler

Top menu: Action -> Create Task. You will get a task configuration window.
Specify a name
Choose the radio button: Run whether the user is logged on or not
Click on the checkbox: Run with highest privileges (if necessary)

Select the Trigger tab on top. Click on the New button.
From the Begin the task drop down, select At startup.

Select the Action tab on top. Click on the New button.
The Action drop down must specify Start a program. Browse and select your Perl script. Add any arguments if necessary.

The other tabs can probably be left alone. But this is the cleanest UI for creating a start up program. I believe you can also edit the registry and specify start up programs/scripts to run there, which is pretty standard practice for installation scripts.

Hope this helps.